# $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA warning still showing up in POST response after setting 'always_populate_raw_post_data' in php.ini to -1

Tags: php, android, laravel-5.1

So i am using PHP 5.6 and building a Laravel 5.1 API and also building an android app.

When i try sending a post request from the android emulator i get the following message along with the proper data/response:

```
Deprecated: Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. 
To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in Unknown on line 0.
```

I know why the error is showing up, but i cant seem to fix it.

The normal fix would be to set always_populate_raw_post_data to -1 but that is not working.

I am thinking of upgrading to a later version of php where $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA has been removed.

any help/advice would be appreciated.

Comment: restart your apache server after set always_populate_raw_post_data to -1

Comment: did that(always knew to), still the same result....

Comment: Are you sure you uncomment the line always_populate_raw_post_data = -1 ?

Comment: Yes i did that - uncommented the line and restarted my Server, infact i have restarted my system (other reasons) after that and the result is the same....

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to php 7.0 fixed it at as expected, i really wanted to avoid upgrading, but it seems that is the only fix in my case as just setting       'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' 
in php 5.6 did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still getting the warning (as I was) run:

```
<?php phpinfo() ?>
```

and look for the value of **Loaded Configuration File** key.

> In my case the `php.ini` used by WAMP was located in:
>
> `C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\bin\php.ini`
>
> (symlink to `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25\phpForApache.ini`)

Edit this file and set `always_populate_raw_post_data = -1`, then restart your server.